# Which tools are recommended for writing/authoring with?

Tags: technique, software, tools

I have to following tools available, looking for other options.

- Microsoft Word
- Sublime Text Editor
- Atom
- Visual Code

I'm a Software Engineer, who is interested in writing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Dean, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  You are in the right place as you make your transition from software engineer to writer.  There is a lot to read here and you're welcome to answer questions too.  This particular question though is very broad and what we call a list question.  So it's likely to get closed.  The answer is use anything you want!  Which tools people use (paper and pencil, Word, or something else) is really based on their personal needs and budget.

Comment: Scrivener. I will never bother with "ideas on paper" ever again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a pen and paper (I handwrite anything important as a first draft) and then Microsoft Word. Depending on how important it is, I also use *Language Tool, Grammarly and ProWriting Aid* (in that order) to check my grammar and style. I use an online version of the OED (free with being a member of my local library), Merriam-Webster and a most usually, a downloaded version of *WordWeb* for checking the meanings of words and their usage. I also use *Poet Assistant* on a phone particularly for synonyms.

Very occasionally I use *Notepad++* and I have written some simple programs myself to check for word usage.

Answer (score 1):

Pen and paper, can't beat it for note's that you don't want/need to share with other people. Any writing app that lets you type fast and collate across phone, tablet, and computer.